# jQuery Find and provide values issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, find

Code is at: http://jsfiddle.net/m9yen/

Issue:

- I have multiple LI's listing FOOD ITEMS
- Each li contains a link (add) and in that href is a rel which holds that specific FOODID
- I now need to have an input box for QUANITY
- I also need to a select with dropdowns for SERVING TYPE (i.e. grams, et which I'll populate)
- End issue is when the add is clicked, I need to get the rel for the href, the value of the input and the selected option **for that specific LI ONLY** and sent it to request.php via ajax.

Now I did have it working specifically with the rel only sine it was a if href is clicked get attr('rel') and submit it via ajax to request.php -- BUT since this requires other values of items outside the href but only within that specific LI, I'm lost and have tried using .find() with no luck what so ever.

NOTE: There will be more than one, possible 50-100 listings (each LI)

Comment: Somebody mentioned .find() but I can't use this since i check if 'link' is clicked

Comment: You need to better explain the problem, "look at the code and you'll see" is not the best way of describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `input` and `select` elements are its siblings you have to use `siblings` method to find them. Since the name of the elements are same as what you are matching use `=` instead of `=^=` and just use `"rel"` to get the attribute value from anchor instead of `"a#rel"`.

```
var returnedResult = $(this).attr('rel') + "-" + $(this).siblings('input[name="servingAmount"]'.val() + "-" $(this).siblings('select[name="servingType"]').val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/m9yen/4/)**

Comment: Would it also just be `$(this).attr('rel')` instead of `$(this).attr('a#rel')`?

Comment: @Ben - It should be just `rel`. Thanks fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/m9yen/3/ - generally tidied up.

- Listening for a click on `#addING` in shorter syntax
- using `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` to prevent link execution
- using `.siblings()...val()` to get values of inputs
- changed `=^=` to just `=` - you're matching the exact name anyway. If you need "starting with", just `^=` will do

Comment: Tried this, it all stopped working, nothing happens and there's no JS errors via this code <http://jsfiddle.net/m9yen/5/> I had this issue before and only .on() worked because .click() was depreciated

Comment: That code works fine for me. Not sure what you're doing wrong hehe.